# Listen to phone state even after boot

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, phone-state-listener

In my app I listen to the phone state events(i.e call received, idle etc) using a `Broadcast Receiver`. Code as below:

```
public class PhoneCallreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private boolean ringing;
    private boolean received;

    public PhoneCallreceiver() {
    }

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.v("ranjith", "enterted receiver");
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    String incomingnumber = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
    String state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
    Log.v("ranjapp", state);

    if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
        ringing = true;
        received = false;
    } 
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".PhoneCallreceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

My problem is I want to start the `BroadCast Receiver`automatically after the device is re-booted. I have a `BroadCast Receiver` to listen to boot but I am not sure how to start the `PhoneCallreceiver` BroadCast receiver.

Manifest.xml

```
   <receiver
        android:name=".backend.BootStarter"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Code:

```
public class BootStarter extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
        PhoneCallreceiver callreceiver = new PhoneCallreceiver();
        context.registerReceiver(callreceiver,new IntentFilter(**what to put here**));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Does BootStarter not strating or it's not registering the phone state broadcast receiver properly?

Comment: BootStarter is starting, but how to start the PhoneCallReceiver within onReceive of BootStarter?

Comment: Have you tried adding boot-completed intent-filter to your .PhoneCallReceiver ?

Comment: If i do so the PhonecallReceiver will be called after boot, but that has code to be executed only when call is received

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to my question, intentfilter action to receive phonestate is `android.telephony.TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED`

My updated code below:

```
public class BootStarter extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
    PhoneCallreceiver callreceiver = new PhoneCallreceiver();
            context.registerReceiver(new PhoneCallreceiver(), new IntentFilter(android.telephony.TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED));
        }
    }
```